# Attempting to use (SSE4) blendvpd with inline assembly in gcc

Tags: gcc, x86-64, sse, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler

I would like to let the compiler choose registers automatically by parameter-izing my inline assembly in my C code, but I'm having some trouble.  Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?  If I use the code that I have commented out (forcing the affiliation with %xmm0), it will compile and get the expected result.  But if I leave it commented out as written here, I get the compiler error:

```
/tmp/ccJxmSbm.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccJxmSbm.s:81: Error: the first operand of `blendvpd' must be `%xmm0'
```

Also, if I do nothing other than remove the printf statement, the code block compiles successfully too.  So it has something to do with moving parameters around to prepare for the printf call.  I have explicitly put in the "Yz" constraint which is supposed to force the use of %xmm0, but it looks like it is not being honored.

Here is the code in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const unsigned long long myConst[2]  = {0x0000000000000000,0xffffffffffffffff};
const unsigned long long myConst2[2] = {0x0000000000000000,0x1111111111111111};
const unsigned long long myConst3[2] = {0x0123456789abcdef,0x0000000000000000};

#define ASSIGN_CONST128( val, const ) \
  val = *((__uint128_t *)const);

int main( void )
{
  register __uint128_t regVal1 /* asm("%xmm0") */ ;
  register __uint128_t regVal2;
  register __uint128_t regVal3;
  ASSIGN_CONST128( regVal1, myConst );
  ASSIGN_CONST128( regVal2, myConst2 );
  ASSIGN_CONST128( regVal3, myConst3 );

  asm( "blendvpd %[mask], %[val1], %[val2]" :
       [val2] "+x" (regVal3) :
       [mask] "Yz" (regVal1),
       [val1] "x"  (regVal2) );

  printf( "REGVAL1: %016llx%016llx (original=%016llx%016llx)\n"
          "REGVAL2: %016llx%016llx (original=%016llx%016llx)\n"
          "REGVAL3: %016llx%016llx (original=%016llx%016llx)\n",
   (unsigned long long)(regVal1>>64), (unsigned long long)regVal1,
   myConst[1], myConst[0],
   (unsigned long long)(regVal2>>64), (unsigned long long)regVal2,
   myConst2[1], myConst2[0],
   (unsigned long long)(regVal3>>64), (unsigned long long)regVal3,
   myConst3[1], myConst3[0] );

  // Expected result:
  // REGVAL1: ffffffffffffffff0000000000000000 (original=ffffffffffffffff0000000000000000)
  // REGVAL2: 11111111111111110000000000000000 (original=11111111111111110000000000000000)
  // REGVAL3: 11111111111111110123456789abcdef (original=00000000000000000123456789abcdef)
}
```

I appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: `__uint128_t` is not the same as `__m128d`. FYI, `icc` crashes on this code, and `clang` refuses to compile.

Comment: Pure ignorance on my part.  When I changed to __m128i (actually want the integer variant, if it makes a difference), I started noticing a lot less hand-holding from the compiler.  Seems like all interactions with objects of this type have to be done in assembly now.  Not necessarily a problem, but it was tough for me to figure it out.

Comment: So now I'm making two "unsigned long long" temp variables and moving the xmmX register contents into them using movlpd/movhpd.  And then I can do my printf against the "unsigned long long" variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the relevant intrinsic?

```
regVal3 = _mm_blendv_pd (regVal1, regVal2, regVal3);
```

As others have noted, `regVal1`, `regVal2` and `regVal3` should all be declared as `__m128d`.

Comment: Again, mostly ignorance.  This is the first time I've worked with embedding assembly in C.  I wanted to minimize or have more direct control over when memory is touched in my application, so it looked like the constraints in the asm() construct would allow that.  Do intrinsics offer the same level of control?

Comment: Looks like my version of GCC does not support SSE4.1 so I won't be able to use this intrinsic.  Your version above looks like the Intel intrinsic.  I found the GCC one uses `__v2df` arguments and is called `__builtin_ia32_blendvpd`.

Comment: Normally the low-level instruction intrinsic (`__builtin_ia32_blendvpd `) is wrapped in a higher level intrinsic (`_mm_blendv_pd`), e.g. in `<smmintrin.h>`:
`__STATIC_INLINE __m128d __attribute__((__always_inline__))
_mm_blendv_pd (__m128d __X, __m128d __Y, __m128d __M)
{
  return (__m128d) __builtin_ia32_blendvpd ((__v2df)__X,
         (__v2df)__Y,
         (__v2df)__M);
}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It turns out blend didn't do exactly what I was hoping for after I got to know how it works.  But I'm still using SSE instructions and 128-bit words in my project.  My goal is to strictly control access to memory and do as much as I can in machine registers.  So it appears that even the intrinsics and enhanced ASM calls don't quite cover this.  You can set up the parameter sources/dests, but GCC will still read or write to memory when it thinks it needs to.  I'm trying to remove as much of the surrounding C code as I can and write straight assembly to compensate.